# How to create loop or function which give all possible combinations of data from Data Frame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"code" : [1,1,2,2,3], "value" : [10, 11, 11, 11, 30]})
```

And I need to create loop which in result give me all combinations of code x value so:

```
1 10
1 11
2 11
3 30
```

How can I do that ? It can be also as a def

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you simply need to use [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Comment: nevertheless i need do it by loop

Comment: A loop would be not pythonic and much slower. If you must use one, you can loop over the rows using `df.iterrows()` and use a set to store already seen rows (as tuples), so that you'll know to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand your question correctly :

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
     print("{} {}".format(row["code"],row["value"]))
```

Please feel free to explain your question further if that is not what you needed. You may provide more examples as well